# Tor Browser keeps kicking me off Ebay

Tags: blocked-services

I tried to logon on to Ebay but it refuses to allow me to login to my account. I sign in with my username and pw, but then it immediately logs out.  Is this the result of Ebay blocking the Tor browser, or am is this Tor blocking some security flaw in the Ebay site?

Comment: This is so much armchair snake oil. Ebay posts cookies when you log in. It also logs your IP address to keep track on you (so does Paypal). Its all part of the control freak way they operate. So Tor disables this so ebay wont log you in.

Comment: Why can't you log in to StackExchange, Wikipedia etc.? All those sites use cookies and Tor Browser allows them to set their cookies. It just changes the cookie handling. So your above statement is not true.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons why you may not be able to log in to a website with tor browser. The three main ones would be

1. The site might specifically be blocking tor users from logging in.
2. The login might require javascript, flash, or some form of cookie that the tor browser bundle has disabled for security reasons.
3. The site rate limits requests or logins by ip address. Since ebay is a popular website and all ebay users exiting from the same tor node appear to have the same ip address, ebay might be blocking all but 10 requests per minute (for example).

Comment: Assuming the answer from nullUser (edited by Lutz Horn) is right (in particular about the first and second issues) this is how it works the mighty Tor browser?
Does not take too much effort for any website to kick tor users out...

Comment: @PatriciaVanNess Tor browser never claimed to be mighty, it claims to be secure and anonymity preserving. Javascript, plugins, and persistent cookies can be used to deanonymize users and so many Tor users prefer to have these things disabled. As for your second point, all users are easy to kick out, not just tor users. Tor is not intended to hide the fact that you are using tor, it is designed to preserve your anonymity. The real question is why would a website want to kick out 3 million people based on the fact that they want to preserve their own privacy?

Answer (score 0):

It is common when a new Tor circuit is formed that websites end your login session. This is because they tie each session to an IP address.

Helps prevent sessionjacking slightly, although it's a nuisance when using Tor.